# .htaccess hide sub-subdirectory in url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Looked for an answer but couldn't find one that solved my specific issue.

The Manager of my website is located under `/manager/php` an and want to remove the "php" from the URL.

For example `https://example.com/manager/php/topkek.php` would become `https://example.com/manager/topkek.php`.

Tried this but it gives an *internal server error* probably because of infinit redirects:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^manager/(.+)$ /manager/php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule causes an infinite rewrite loop as your pattern `^manager/(.+)$` also matches the substitution string `/manager/php/$1` . You need to fix it so that the pattern can not match the destination path. You can exclude the `/php` path in your regex to fix the error.

```
 Options +FollowSymlinks
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^manager/((?!php).+)$ /manager/php/$1 [L]
```

Or you can use a `RewriteCond` directive to exclude the destination  path

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/manager/php 
 RewriteRule ^manager/(.+)$ /manager/php/$1 [L]
```